# Read in a csv with a different separator based on the each column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Column id and runtime are comma-separated. However, column **genres** is separated by Pipe(|).
`df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=',')` results in the table below. However, I can't conduct any queries on column **genres**, for instance finding the most popular genre by year? Is it possible to separate pipe into separate rows?

```
df.head()
    id  runtime genres                                       Year
0   135397  124 Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller    2000
1   76341   120 Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller    2002
2   262500  119 Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller           2001
3   140607  136 Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Fantasy     2000
4   168259  137 Action|Crime|Thriller                        1999
```

Comment: You don't want to split the `genres` in the same way as the other fields, because the number of strings appears to vary with row.

Answer (score 1):

You're better reading the file as is, then split the genres into new rows with pandas [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = df.assign(genres = df.genres.str.split('|')).explode('genres')
```

so that you can easily manipulate your data.

---

For example, to get the most frequent (*i.e.* mode) genres per year:

```
df.groupby('Year').genres.apply(lambda x: x.mode()).droplevel(1)
```

To identify the counts:

```py
def get_all_max(grp):
    counts = grp.value_counts()
    return counts[counts==counts.max()]

df.groupby('Year').genres.apply(get_all_max)\
.rename_axis(index={None:'Genre'}).to_frame(name='Count')
```